# Control elements display with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display the contents of particular rows that are checked in in my checkbox

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>All
<input type="checkbox">One
<input type="checkbox">Two
<input type="checkbox">Three
<table border="2">
<tr class="one">
<td>1 </td>
<td>one</td>
</tr>
<tr class="two">
<td>2</td>
<td>two</td>
</tr>
<tr class="three">
<td>3
</td>
<td>three</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
<script>
if ($('.one').is(":checked")) {
        $("input:checkbox").text();
  // it is checked
}

if ($('.two').is(":checked")) {
        $("input:checkbox").text();
  // it is checked
}

if ($('.three').is(":checked")) {
        $("input:checkbox").text();
  // it is checked
}
</script>
```

I expect to get the data of the row that only if it is checked and by default it should show all the values.

Comment: 1) you don't have an element with `id="one"`. 2) `input type="checkbox"` doesn't have `text` property.

Comment: It doesn't work. I did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle separately the action on the *"all"* checkbox from the other group of checkboxes.

Also, it makes no sense to have all the other checkboxes unchecked if *"all"* is actually checked. All is all. So check all!

Don't use classes, the selectors could get clumsy or incorrect one day, instead use the `data-*` attribute:

```js
const $tog = $('.tog'),
  $all = $tog.filter('[value="all"]'),
  $num = $tog.not('[value="all"]'),
  $row = $('[data-row]');

function rowToggler() {
  const val = this.value;

  if (val === 'all') {

    $num.prop('checked', this.checked);      // handle group
    $row.toggleClass('none', !this.checked); // and all rows

  } else {

    $all.prop('checked', $num.filter(':checked').length === $num.length); // handle all
    $row.filter((i, el) => $(el).data('row') === val).toggleClass('none', !this.checked); // and specific rows

  }
}

$tog.on('change', rowToggler);
rowToggler.call($all[0]); // Dry init
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="tog" value="all" checked>All

<input type="checkbox" class="tog" value="one">One
<input type="checkbox" class="tog" value="two">Two
<input type="checkbox" class="tog" value="three">Three

<table border="2">
  <tr data-row="one">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-row="two">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-row="three">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't understand that it works perfectly fine over here but if I copy-paste and try to run it from my pc it just doesn't work at all.

Comment: @anusha Notice that there are changes in HTML too

Comment: @AnushaNeupane not sure to understand your question. Any error in console? What API?

Answer (score -1):

First, you want to trap all the checkbox clicks. Use `$('input[type=checkbox').click()` to trap these click events

Then you want to determine which checkbox was clicked. If checkbox "ALL" you want to do one set of tests, if one of the others you do something else.

#### DEMO:

```js
$('input[type=checkbox').click(function(){
   //get id, arrayize on underscore, take 2nd arr element eg. two
   let nom = this.id.split('_')[1];

   if (nom == 'all'){
      if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
         uncheck_all_checkboxes();
         show_all_table_rows();
      }else{
         alert('Now, you finish making it hide all rows');
      }
   }else{
      $('#cb_all').prop('checked', false);
      verify_all_checkboxes();
   }
});
function verify_all_checkboxes(){
   $('input[type=checkbox').each(function(idx, el){
      var nom = this.id.split('_')[1];
      if ( !$(el).is(":checked")) {
         console.log(nom);
         $('table').find('tr.' + nom).addClass('hidden');
      }else{
         $('table').find('tr.' + nom).removeClass('hidden');
      }
   });
}
function uncheck_all_checkboxes(){
   $('input[type=checkbox').each(function(idx, el){
      var nom = this.id.split('_')[1];
      if (nom !== 'all'){
         $(this).prop('checked', false);
      }
   });
}
function show_all_table_rows(){
   $('table tr').removeClass('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cb_all" type="checkbox" checked>All
<input id="cb_one" type="checkbox">One
<input id="cb_two" type="checkbox">Two
<input id="cb_three" type="checkbox">Three
<table border="2">
  <tr class="one">
    <td>1 </td>
    <td>one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="two">
    <td>2</td>
    <td>two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="three">
    <td>3
    </td>
    <td>three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would just `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` of a `.hide` class.

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
$(function(){ // jQuery load start
var check_all = $('#check_all'), check_one = $('#check_one'), check_two = $('#check_two'), check_three = $('#check_three'), trs = $('#output_table>tbody>tr'), tr1 = trs.eq(0), tr2 = trs.eq(1), tr3 = trs.eq(2);
check_one.click(function(){
  if(check_one.is(':checked')){
    tr1.removeClass('hide');
  }
  else{
    tr1.addClass('hide');
  }
});
check_two.click(function(){
  if(check_two.is(':checked')){
    tr2.removeClass('hide');
  }
  else{
    tr2.addClass('hide');
  }
});
check_three.click(function(){
  if(check_three.is(':checked')){
    tr3.removeClass('hide');
  }
  else{
    tr3.addClass('hide');
  }
});
check_all.click(function(){
  var cv = check_all.is(':checked');
  $('.indi').each(function(i, e){
    $(e).prop('checked', cv);
  });
  if(cv){
    trs.removeClass('hide');
  }
  else{
    trs.addClass('hide');
  }
});
}); // jQuery load end
//]]>
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0;
}
html,body{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
body{
  background:#ccc;
}
#content{
  padding:7px;
}
.hide{
  display:none;
}
label{
  display:inline-block; margin-left:3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1' />
    <title>Test Template</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='content'>
    <input id='check_all' type='checkbox' checked='checked' /><label for='check_all'>All</label>
    <input class='indi' id='check_one' type='checkbox' checked='checked' /><label for='check_one'>One</label>
    <input class='indi' id='check_two' type='checkbox' checked='checked' /><label for='check_two'>Two</label>
    <input class='indi' id='check_three' type='checkbox' checked='checked' /><label for='check_three'>Three</label>
    <table id='output_table'>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>1</th><td>one</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>2</th><td>two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>3</th><td>three</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```